# Page links not always showing at the bottom of stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, navigation

I can't reproduce this every time, but I've taken screenshot to prove it's not just madness....

Note how between the bottom of the question and the bottom bar, there are no page navigation/size links. Also the "PEAK" bit overflows on the right.

[alt text http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/1643/brokenshame.png](http://img694.imageshack.us/img694/1643/brokenshame.png)

Here's what it should look like:

[alt text http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/8761/shameonskeet.png](http://img138.imageshack.us/img138/8761/shameonskeet.png)

Chrome 5.0.375.99 (beta channel), Windows 7.

EDIT: I've just seen it again in one window after opening 4 in a row... and the bottom question shown is the same for both the broken window and the working one, so it *is* getting all the questions...

I didn't mention before, this is the Questions tab, set to "Newest" sort order and 50 questions per page.

EDIT: I've also just seen the same thing on IE8. I don't have Firefox on this box to try to reproduce it there, but I can do so when I get home.

Comment: did you mean "chrome 6"? because chrome 5 is not a beta.

Comment: @Jeff: My "about" dialog says "Chrome 5.0.375.99 beta". I thought 6 was the dev channel... Anyway, beta or not, it's 5.0.375.99 :)

Comment: @Jeff: Btw, if there's any other information that would be relevant next time I see it, just let me know. I wish I knew what triggered it - if it were just on the 3G connection I'm on now, I'd put it down to that, but it happened at home this morning too...

Comment: possibly related: [answers not loading completely](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53080/answers-not-loading-completely).

Comment: Reproduced on a 32M DSL connection.

Comment: @tobias not even remotely related. finger itching over "delete" button.

Comment: @Jeff I posted about this prior to Skeet (some kind of claim to fame?) might want to close up my question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57468/sporadically-the-paging-links-on-the-newest-questions-page-disappear

Comment: @Jeff well, sorry for not closely related (obviously it's no dupe) but they both concern incorrect site displaying. But if you prefer, I'll delete the comment, just say the word

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can reproduce in IE7.

This only happens when this add appears: http://img249.imageshack.us/img249/8899/thebadadd.gif
Other ads don't cause this.

The navigation buttons move to this place: http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/2437/thebuttons.gif

Comment: I can reproduce on Firefox 3.6 Windows.

Comment: Accepted this as the most useful bit of repro - nicely spotted.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to some fancy jquery code in that ad which apparently is wrong.

I updated it reverting to non-fancy basic `<div><script></div>` which seems to be better.