# Sanity check: How did my answer ended up on superuser.com?

Tags: support, answers, stack-exchange, migration

I just registered at http://superuser.com.
I got my 100 rep for accociating, and then suddenly a `Teacher` badge.

I clicked [the helpful link](https://superuser.com/questions/110487/how-to-prevent-a-file-being-copied-or-cut-in-windows-file-system/110490#110490) (mod rights required), and here is my answer, answered by me, which I never answered on superuser.

I did post this answer [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290149/how-to-prevent-a-file-being-copied-or-cut-in-windows-file-system/2290152#2290152), but obviously, that was only *after* the answer has been migrated, because I wasn't registered on superuser back then.

As far as my permissions let me see, the question was not first migrated to superuser and then migrated back. It originated at superuser and then ended up at stackoverflow.

So I'm really curious, how did my answer end up there? And also look at the comment, it exists on both sites, posted by same user, and the link to the user points to their proper site-specific user page.

Comment: @Jeff Yes, thanks for the edit. I completely forgot we had the `[support]` tag. Only `[bug]`, `[feature-request]` and `[discussion]` made it to my mind for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure? At first glance, this is what I see:
Feb 18, 7:57 — question asked on SU
Feb 18, 8:51 — you answer question
Feb 18, 16:20 — question migrated to SO

You can't possibly have answered on SO before the migration took place. Note that you didn't necessarily have to be registered on SU to get credit. You clearly [have an account on SU now](https://superuser.com/users/52365/gserg).

Okay, I see that your SU account was created today. If your cookies from previous unregistered visits to SU were still on your computer, the system could have associated your old answer with your new account automatically.

Comment: Unless @GSerg hit that wire with the connecting hook at precisely 88mph the instant the lightning strikes the tower....

Comment: @GSerg, hm... perhaps... you let someone else use your computer, and that person visited SU? Maybe you didn't realize it was an SE site at the time?

Comment: (sorry for deleting the comment, I suddenly felt it was a bit too confident) I think the only possible reason I could ever ended up on superuser and even posted an aswer without being registered is if I saw [that add](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57507/page-links-not-always-showing-at-the-bottom-of-stackoverflow-com/57518#57518) and it was related to a Raymond post (in which case I'm usually keen to post a link). Was this add in rotation back then, I wonder?

Comment: @GSerg, now that question, I cannot answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Popular is correct, this answer was associated after you created a new account on Super User.

This answer also happens to be on a question that was migrated from SU to SO, so it is deleted.